# Using Databinding and maxlines make ellipsize not work in TextView

Tags: android, textview, android-databinding, ellipsize

when I replace maxlines with singleLine or replace text(databinding) with static text, ellipsize = "end" is fine. And this is not constraintLayout's problem.
how can I fix this problem except truncating text and replacing by adding '...'?

Comment: Hello Roc! Welcome to StackOverflow! You could add a screenshot image to your question and the mentioned part of the code to make it more "visual" and improve the chance to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, ellipsis got broken by `setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance())`, used to get links working.